# Visual Basic- How do i Display a message box when a trigger in oracle is fired

Tags: vb.net, oracle, basic

Okay so I am using visual basic as a user interface for my oracle database. I have triggers implemented into oracle already. I want to show that my triggers work in visual basic so I am inserting data that will cause the database to fail and the triggers to be fired up. In visual basic, it just crashes, instead I want a messagebox to display instead of it crashing. How would I do this?

```
Private Sub TRANSACTIONBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TRANSACTIONBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
        Me.Validate()
        Me.TRANSACTIONBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.DataSet)
```

the line below this is the one that is it doesn't like

```
Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.DataSet)
```

---

Here is what I Have now? It doesn't like the word Exception though

```
Private Sub TRANSACTIONBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TRANSACTIONBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
        Me.Validate()
        Me.TRANSACTIONBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Try
        Catch exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error", "Error")
        End Try
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.DataSet)
End Sub
```

Comment: [Catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx) the exception.

Comment: I have attempted, but don't know how to fix it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it wrong, please read the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx) properly.

```
Private Sub TRANSACTIONBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TRANSACTIONBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
    Try
        Me.Validate()
        Me.TRANSACTIONBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.DataSet)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Flower arranging eh? LOL yeah, I saw it. Funny dawg ;-) OP would have more luck with that.

Comment: I got a great laugh out of it :-)) too funny